# Mysql CASE NOT FOUND for CASE STATEMENT on a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, case-statement

im trying to create a stored procedure that have multiples CASE STATEMENTS
I have the following stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
CASE @olds
WHEN 'emp' THEN
    CASE @news
    WHEN 'loc' THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe-1,pg=pg+1 WHERE id=@eqloc;
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe-1,pp=pp+1 WHERE id=@eqvis;
        UPDATE partidos SET `eqgan`=@news WHERE id=@mst;
        UPDATE log_partidos SET `status`=@news WHERE `match`=@mst;
    WHEN 'vis' THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe-1,pg=pg+1 WHERE id=@eqvis;
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe-1,pp=pp+1 WHERE id=@eqloc;
        UPDATE partidos SET `eqgan`=@news WHERE id=@mst;
        UPDATE log_partidos SET `status`=@news WHERE `match`=@mst;
    END CASE;
WHEN 'loc' THEN
    CASE @news
    WHEN 'emp' THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe+1,pg=pg-1 WHERE id=@eqloc;
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe+1,pp=pp-1 WHERE id=@eqvis;
        UPDATE partidos SET `eqgan`=@news WHERE id=@mst;
        UPDATE log_partidos SET `status`=@news WHERE `match`=@mst;
    WHEN 'vis' THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET pp=pp-1,pg=pg+1 WHERE id=@eqvis;
        UPDATE equipos SET pg=pg-1,pp=pp+1 WHERE id=@eqloc;
        UPDATE partidos SET `eqgan`=@news WHERE id=@mst;
        UPDATE log_partidos SET `status`=@news WHERE `match`=@mst;
    END CASE;
WHEN 'vis' THEN
    CASE @news
    WHEN 'emp' THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe+1,pg=pg-1 WHERE id=@eqvis;
        UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe+1,pp=pp-1 WHERE id=@eqloc;
        UPDATE partidos SET `eqgan`=@news WHERE id=@mst;
        UPDATE log_partidos SET `status`=@news WHERE `match`=@mst;
    WHEN 'loc' THEN
        UPDATE equipos SET pp=pp-1,pg=pg+1 WHERE id=@eqloc;
        UPDATE equipos SET pg=pg-1,pp=pp+1 WHERE id=@eqvis;
        UPDATE partidos SET `eqgan`=@news WHERE id=@mst;
        UPDATE log_partidos SET `status`=@news WHERE `match`=@mst;
    END CASE;
END CASE;
END
```

Everytime im executing this procedure i got the following error is: "Case not found for CASE statement"
What im doing wrong?

Comment: Is it finding a case that isn't in your WHEN statements? Have you tried adding ELSE into your statements to see if it's falling through anywhere?

Answer (score 29):

This is a MySQL specific problem.
In MySQL, a case must always have a valid match, thus an ELSE clause.
And as the statement after the match cannot be empty, you can fill it up with an empty block like so:

```
ELSE BEGIN END;
```

So a valid case would be, for example:

```
CASE @news  
  WHEN 'emp' THEN  
    UPDATE equipos SET pe=pe+1,pg=pg-1 WHERE id=@eqvis;  
  WHEN 'loc' THEN  
    UPDATE equipos SET pp=pp-1,pg=pg+1 WHERE id=@eqloc;  
  ELSE BEGIN END;  
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 4):

That error means one of the 'case' statements can't find a match. Are you sure variables olds and news contain right values? Try to change last 'when' in each case to 'else' and see if your procedure works then.